# How to share a game created with the free version of Game Maker Studio 2?

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I've recently downloaded Game Maker studio for free and made my first game. Now, I'd like to share it with others.

I tried to use the "Export" button and it only creates a duplicate project. If I click the "Create executable" button, it says "Packages cannot be built for the selected platform" in an error box.

I looked up how to make a `.exe` file and how to create an application, but the "Create application" button from the file directory doesn't exist in my version of Game Maker Studio 2. Some said that the error message when creating a `.exe` file is caused by a UWP license issue, but I don't know what a UWP license is or how to change it.

So, how do I create a sharable game file that isn't a project file? And, if the "Create executable" button is the only way, why can't packages be built for my "platform"?

My IDE is v2.3.4.580 and my runtime is v2.3.4.442.

Comment: UWP usually refers to "Universal Windows Platform". Are you running on Windows and building for Windows? If so, what version?

Comment: im running windows 10, and building for that. also, I've been looking around some more, and some versions of game maker seem to have the target icon in the corner that allows you to change the "platform", many people have windows, macos, ubuntu, etc, but mine is only "test", I think that my be my problem, but idk how to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current problem with creating executables is due to the licence you're using, not (necessarily) the UWP export configuration.

The Free license for GameMaker Studio 2 gives you full access to the IDE (i.e. usage and assets limitations were removed) and lets you use the application for testing and learning purposes. You can't build game executables and share them with other people though.

This is the Free license description from [the YoYo Games website](https://www.yoyogames.com/en/get):

> #### Free
>
> **GameMaker Studio 2**
> Unlimited access to the IDE (integrated development environment) and learning materials.

When you *export* a project, GMS2 creates an *exact* copy of the project–which includes ALL assets, configuration files and local settings–in a directory of choice. This way, you can 'clone' a game project without the need to manually browse and copy/paste all files, some of which may be unnecessary (e.g. IDE temp files).

If you want to share the game with fellow developers, the above is the way to go. But, if you want to *release* the game for others to play, that's a different matter. You will need an Indie or Enterprise licence, for they include what they call Desktop/Web/Mobile 'exports' but are actually platform-specific **build** plug-ins.

According to the YoYo Games website, the cheapest license you can get is:

> #### Indie
>
> **GameMaker Studio 2**
> Unlimited access to the IDE (integrated development environment) and learning materials.
> **Desktop Exports**
> Windows, macOS, and Linux platforms exports.
> **Web Export**
> HTML5 platform export.
> **Mobile Exports**
> iOS, Android, Amazon Fire, Android TV, and tvOS platforms exports.
> **UWP Export**
> Universal Windows Platform (includes Xbox One Creators program) exports.

Comment: ahh thank you, this makes perfect sense and answers my question! well, I'm glad I know that now! would you happen to know a similar alternative game engine, same skill level, with free release options? thank you!!

Comment: If the DnD system is a must for you, you can check out [Stencyl](http://www.stencyl.com/) or [Construct](https://www.construct.net). They provide visual-driven scripting tools for programming a game from scratch. Unfortunately, they all have paid subscription plans for various audiences. On the other hand, different dev programs let you publish your game on desktop, mobile, and web; they don't provide a DnD interface though, and require you have some base knowledge about actual programming/scripting.

Comment: As a different solution, you may search for previous GMS versions (such as GameMaker Studio 1) on the Internet. Official support for them is discontinued, and devs are recommended to upgrade to the latest versions; however, these may be still working and even including some of the paid features you're looking for.

Comment: wow- could an old version possibly render my existing game (make with gamemaker 2) as a sharable game?

Comment: New projects cannot be opened with previous versions of the tool, you must code it once again. But, most functions are still the same, so it's more about copy-pasting scripts and reimporting assets, with only minor changes to be dealt with manually.

Comment: i think ill definitely look for that!! thank you<3 do you happen to know which old versions would be best to look for-? sorry for the late reply, but btw, earlier you addressed various game platforms that used dnd, well, I'm not a fan of dnd and enjoyed the simple GML language, so what programs would you be referring to that required programming/scripting but let you publish for free?

Comment: If scripting is your thing, you could take a look at IDEs with programming/scripting language support, such as Unity (C#), Godot (GDScript, VisualScript, C#, C++), Cocos2D (JavaScript, TypeScript). They all let you export your game for free, some with limitations (e.g. Unity's splash screen when using the free version, not a big deal actually). Also, there're plenty of guides and tutorials to get started with, as well as many Q&A threads here on GameDev and other community forums. You can read [this article](https://thomasgervraud.com/best-2d-game-engine/) or similars to get an insight.

Comment: thank you very much! im sorry for the late reply, but one more quick question, what older versions would be the most likely to be able to export the final game, free?

Comment: nvm nvm, i figured it out, its a slow go but its working, thank you!! if you have any tips on how to import sprites and stuff easier, lemme know, that's the hardest part